# Rendering PDF with css on the fly client side webapp

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, client-side, server-side

I would like to render a PDF on the fly using HTML that is generated from d3 (chart/table with dynamic data), add style to it (css/inline-styles).

I managed to generate a pdf out of an html table though, what I need is a lot more style to be added.

I've tried using different libs though they provide a poor way to style (mostly limiting to font sizes/colors and margins), thought about trying html2canvas and then jsPDF, though that didn't work.

Almost everywhere I investigated I've found developers trying to do a very styled pdf using css, they turned to do so server-side (mainly phantomjs).

What are the technical difficulties found in client-side that enable adding a css via server-side but not in client-side ? shouldn't this be possible on both ends ?

Comment: PDFs are neither HTML nor CSS and cannot be rendered or styled by either. I think you may be confused.

Comment: Client-side : managed to generate a very unstyled table to a downloadable PDF. Server-side : managed to output a d3 styled chart to a PDF file